# Can you tell me why my my props.id is coming out to be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is the file where in the console, I am trying to print `props.name`, `props.images` and `props.id`. `name` and `images` are correct but the `id` is coming out to be `undefined`.
You can see in the function `changetext` I am printing the 3 things in the console.

Moreover, if I am using `props.images` instead of `props.id` then it is working.

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css' 
import { infoarray } from './Menu'
import { useState } from 'react'
export default function Pricetag(props) {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("Add to Cart")
  const [disvalue, setdisvalue] = useState(false)
  const [mystyles, setmystyles] = useState({
    color:'white',
    background:'#094784'
  })

  const changetext = (e) =>{
      console.log("that  -> "  , props.name , props.images ,props.id) ; 
      if(mystyles.color=== 'white'){
          setmystyles({
            color : 'white',
            background : 'red'
          })
      }
      setdisvalue(true); 
      setvalue('Added to Cart ✔'); 
  }

  return (
        <div className="button">
          <button disabled={disvalue} style={mystyles} className='btn no1' 
           onClick={ ()=> { infoarray.push(props.id); changetext(); }}>
            {value}
          </button>
          <br></br>
        </div>
  )
}
```

infoarray is an array declared as follows

```
const infoarray = [];
export { infoarray };
export const changedArray = newinfoArray => infoarray = newinfoArray;
```

data is a js object  looks like this

```
export const data = [
    {
        id:1 ,
        name: "Almond Cake" ,
        images : images01
    },
    
    {
        id:2 ,
        name: "Cartoon cake" ,
        images : images02
    },
    
    {
        id:3 , 
        name: "Choco pie cake " ,
        images : images03
    }
]
```

What is wrong here?

Edit

```
import React from 'react'
import { data } from './Data'
import './cartstyle.css'
import Cartitems from './Cartitems';
import { infoarray } from './Menu';
export default function Gotocart() {
  infoarray.forEach(element => {
    console.log("this is the element -> " , element);
  });
  return (
    <div className='cartbody'>

      <div className="cart-info" id='cartinformation'>
        {
          data.map((e) =>{
            return infoarray.map((ank) =>{
                  if(ank==e.id){
                  return (<Cartitems key={e.id} name={e.name} images ={e.images}/>);
                  }
                  else {
                    return null ; 
                  }
                });
          })
        }
      </div>
  )
}
```

using Pricetag

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Pricetag from './Pricetag'
import image80 from './assets/cake80.jpeg'
import image81 from './assets/cake81.jpeg'
import image82 from './assets/cake82.jpeg'
import image83 from './assets/cake83.jpeg'


export default function Cakebody(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Link to='/' className="menulink con112 ">
                <div className='name1' >Back to home page</div>
            </Link>
            <div className="headingbody">
                {props.title}
            </div>
            <hr className='latestline' />
            <div className='container1'>
                <Pricetag id='52' images={image80} name="Doll Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag id='53' images={image81} name="Mixed Platte Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag id='54' images={image82} name="Pinata  Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag id='55' images={image83} name="Bomb  Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
            </div>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: Can u share the code where u r calling Pricetag component?

Comment: Sir the first code is pricetag.jsx

Comment: I mean where u are binding your data with component. Either u r using map function or any other loop. That area of code please

Comment: I have added in edit

Comment: Where is the Pricetag used?

Comment: I have 6 files where it is being used I have added such a code in edit please check

Comment: It's impossible to recreate the bug. Would you mind sharing a Codesandbox with the running code?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your concern I changed the id in data.js to string and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Pricetag component called the same way Cartitems is in Gotocart? (actually I'm somehow guessing that they're the same else there's no link between the 2 files)
If so, then you passed the id as "key", not as "id", you should do both for React sake and to be able to access props.id within it.

What you most likely have:

```
<Pricetag key={e.id} name={e.name} images={e.images}/>
```

What you want:

```
<Pricetag key={e.id} id={e.id} name={e.name} images={e.images}/>
```

Unrelated: I believe infoarray looks like it should be a proper React state, with a setter, passed as a prop to child components.
Else things will be more and more messy the more you work with it.

Comment: Thanks, for your concern I changed the id in data.js to string and it worked

Answer (score -2):

⚠️  I am new to react.

Please use `data-*` attribute in react. This may be caused by react-oriented behaviour as react transcripts your statically written classes and ids to some kind of arbitraries.

In my opinion,
The pricetag component should be

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css' 
import { infoarray } from './Menu'
import { useState } from 'react'
export default function Pricetag(props) {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("Add to Cart")
  const [disvalue, setdisvalue] = useState(false)
  const [mystyles, setmystyles] = useState({
    color:'white',
    background:'#094784'
  })

  const changetext = (e) =>{
      console.log("that shit -> "  , props.name , props.images ,props['data-*']) ; 
      if(mystyles.color=== 'white'){
          setmystyles({
            color : 'white',
            background : 'red'
          })
      }
      setdisvalue(true); 
      setvalue('Added to Cart ✔'); 
  }

  return (
        <div className="button">
          <button disabled={disvalue} style={mystyles} className='btn no1' 
           onClick={ ()=> { infoarray.push(props['data-*']); changetext(); }}>
            {value}
          </button>
          <br></br>
        </div>
  )
}
```

The usage pricetag component should be as follow.

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Pricetag from './Pricetag'
import image80 from './assets/cake80.jpeg'
import image81 from './assets/cake81.jpeg'
import image82 from './assets/cake82.jpeg'
import image83 from './assets/cake83.jpeg'


export default function Cakebody(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Link to='/' className="menulink con112 ">
                <div className='name1' >Back to home page</div>
            </Link>
            <div className="headingbody">
                {props.title}
            </div>
            <hr className='latestline' />
            <div className='container1'>
                <Pricetag data-id='52' images={image80} name="Doll Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag data-id='53' images={image81} name="Mixed Platte Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag data-id='54' images={image82} name="Pinata  Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag data-id='55' images={image83} name="Bomb  Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
            </div>
        
    )
}
```